# Como enviar Google Chart por email?

Tags: php, envio-de-email, google-charts

Qual seria uma solução viável para enviar um Chart através de email, via PHP? Para obter o Chart, utilizo da seguinte forma:

```js
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
              google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
              function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                 ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
                 ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333', ],
                 ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver'],
                 ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold'],
                 ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2' ]
               ]);
    
                var options = {
                  title: 'Company Performance',
                  hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
                  vAxis: {minValue: 0}
                };
    
                var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    
    
                google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
                 chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
                 console.log(chart_div.innerHTML);
               });
    
                chart.draw(data, options);
              }
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    
            <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Dessa forma ele me retorna o Chart em uma versão "printável".

Comment: Tirando como conclusão os componetes de texto que usam formatação, você terá que jogar seu html no corpo do email.

Comment: Sim, mas a API do Google Charts é chamada apenas no cliente e dessa forma não funciona num email. Estou em busca de uma alternativa viável para obter esse chart do lado do servidor e enviar apenas a imagem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Charts são desenhados utilizando SVG. Alguns provedores de emails fornecem leitura de SVG, outros não. A solução que encontrei foi [converter SVG para PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809194/convert-svg-image-to-png-with-php) e salvar o arquivo PNG no servidor e incluir uma tag `<img src="">` no corpo do email.

### Do Google Chart ao PHP

O Google Chart trabalha no Front-end. PHP é uma linguagem server-side. Você precisará executar o frontend para que o gráfico seja desenhado e, posteriormente, coletar todo o SVG gerado e encaminhá-lo ao PHP. Com jQuery, você poderia pegar o conteúdo utilizando algo simples, como

```
var content = jQuery('#chart_div').html();
```

Feito isso, utilize uma chamada Ajax para entregar o conteúdo ao servidor para que possa ser enviado por email.

*Observações: Particularmente, eu preferi escrever o SVG no próprio PHP do que utilizar o Google Chart. Você pode aprender como fazer gráficos utilizando SVG e fazer com que o próprio PHP escreva todo o conteúdo SVG e converta para PNG. Dessa forma, não há necessidades de execuções de script front-end. O próprio servidor se encarregaria de tudo.*

### Convertendo SVG para PNG

```
   $path = 'path/to/file.png';

    $im = new Imagick();
    $im->readImageBlob($svg_value);

    /* png settings */
    $im->setImageFormat("png24");
    // $im->resizeImage(720, 445, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);  /* Optional, if you need to resize */

    $im->writeImage($path); /* (or .jpg) */
    $im->clear();
    $im->destroy();
```

Comment: [Aqui](http://keepcoding.ehsanabbasi.com/php/convert-google-chart-to-png-and-pdf/) se segue o mesmo conceito.